# (Javascript) How to force the download of an image using iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, bdmultidownloader

My requirement is to select a bunch of images and download them all, all at the same time.

I'm using this library (https://github.com/biesiad/multiDownload) that works pretty well with other files than iamges. When it is image, it doesn't work.

My conclusions is that the browser perceives images differently from other binary files.

I've checked on Google Chrome and all the files that work using that plugin, they are cancelled (developer tools > network) but the images aren't.

Is there any way to tell browser that it's a binary like all the other files? Is there any way?

Many thanks

---

The function is implemented like that:

```
var methods = {
    _download: function (options) {
        var triggerDelay = (options && options.delay) || 100;
        var cleaningDelay = (options && options.cleaningDelay) || 1000;

        this.each(function (index, item) {
            methods._createIFrame(item, index * triggerDelay, cleaningDelay);
        });
        return this;
    },

    _createIFrame: function (item, triggerDelay, cleaningDelay) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var frame = $('<iframe style="display: none;" ' +
                          'class="multi-download-frame"></iframe>');
            frame.attr('src', $(item).attr('href') || $(item).attr('src'));
            $(item).after(frame);
            setTimeout(function () { frame.remove(); }, cleaningDelay);
        }, triggerDelay);
    }
};

$.fn.multiDownload = function(options) {
    return methods._download.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: The information that tells the browser what to do is sent from the server in headers added to the response. You'd need to look at what headers are being sent for files that download and compare those with headers added to the image files. Any fixes would need to be applied at the server.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
The [README.md](https://github.com/biesiad/multiDownload/blob/master/README.md) on multiDownload on Github says...

> Important: All $('.my_links') elements must have defined "href" attribute. "href" must point to documents that generate proper HTML headers ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_filename").

The solution? What they said: send out the following header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="picture.jpg"
```

Comment: I saw that and on my HTTP response is already like that: Content-disposition: attachment; filename="2013_10_23_01_11_38r7dsoktex17u5dlaj76zgz5rm4n1h2dh.png"

Comment: But anyone have tried this plugin with images on recent browsers? Can you give me an example of a working HTTP request for images? Tks

Comment: @CarlosMonteiro I have never tried the plugin. If you go to the picture the plugin is referencing, however, it should download in your browser, or a save dialog should pop up. The plugin cannot force a download -- it is just doing a mass download of many files which are, by default, automatically downloaded if you go directly to the URL. This only makes sense to me.

I cannot give you a working demo, but I have used this method (attachment header) before.

Comment: @CarlosMonteiro Can the plugin download HTML? If it can't, it would make sense. The browser by default downloads files such as ZIPs, EXEs, etc. But pictures and HTML pages would be viewed, instead of downloaded, in the browser. (After all, you wouldn't want to go to a webpage and instead of looking at everything, the browser would download everything!)

Comment: I understand that. But is this useless for images? I'm using it to download a bunch of pictures from a gallery! Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: @CarlosMonteiro I don't know of any other way. And yes, this should work for images.